# collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath - does not get called

Tags: xcode, swift

When app launches, there are several cells contain imageView. One of them will animate:

```
var cell = logoCollectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: 1, inSection: 0))
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, delay: 0.5, options:UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat | UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse,
    animations: {cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.2, 1.2)},
    completion:nil)
```

Everything works fine except this animated cell. When I click it, it doesn't call `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath`. I have to click other cells first, then this animated cell will call `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath` when I click it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When animation is in progress touch events is disabled. This is default behavior. In order to enable touch events you need to give the option `UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I shall read the documentation carefully. Thanks again.